# Public User Profile Page in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, profile, public

I am working on a project in Zend Framework in which the logged in users must have a public profile page. For Example,

```
http://www.example.com/user_x
```

But when i searched Google regarding this, i couldn't find a solution. As i know in Zend, all pages will come only under the 'public' folder.That is, every zend Url is following the below format,

```
http://www.example.com/public/controller/action
```

So, how to create a URL to a users profile with Dynamic Contents from Database?

Can anyone help me? I am Using ZF 1.11 !

Comment: so you want to make a page for every user?

Comment: what do you mean by "all pages will come only under the 'public' folder"?

Comment: Yes Amit. @Tim : What i mean is, whenever we access a page in Zend, it Comes under like <domain>/public/controller/action

Comment: Any ideas please tell me. In so much need of this for my work!

Comment: you need to add each model and routes to the module.config.php file

Comment: Can you explain a bit more @mssb

Comment: actually I did not understand you problem. did you try to add new controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ZF routes give you URLs in the format:

```
http://www.example.com/module/controller/action
http://www.example.com/controller/action
```

If you have 'public' at the start of your URLs then there is something wrong with your vhost setup (make sure your document root points at the public folder, not the root of your project).

To answer your query, you can setup a custom route to allow your user profile URLs, but if you want the username to be at the start of the URL you need to do this in a way that won't break other routes. I wrote a blog post about doing this specific scenario a while back, see: http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework

Comment: Tim, The Virtual Hosts Setup is done. But still how will i overcome the controller/action params. I am not much aware of writing Routers. Could you please Help me out in this too...! I need http://www.example.com/user_x to redirect to a controller say "user" with action "index". Do you have any links on how and where to write routers

Comment: Adding custom routes is what allows you to get other URL structures working. You may wish to have a read through the routing section of th e manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: Thanks Tim, I got it working now. And that was a super Blog Post. Did helped me a lot.